# Why floating point number 333.50 is double

Tags: java, floating-point, double

Why in this line the floating point number is treated as double? I thought float has enough space to hold that number.

```
float f = (float)333.50;
```

Comment: `333.50` is a double literal. A float literal would be `333.50f`. Basically, double is the default.

Comment: In C and C++ the type *is* contingent on the magnitude of the literal, albeit for integral types. This is a fair question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default floating point literal is `double` in java , if you want the value to float you may do this

```
float f = 333.5f
```

Answer (score 3):

The value `333.50` can be represented in the `float` type but is a **double literal**. Use `333.50F` to have a **float literal**.
The specification, see [Oracle Java documentation about Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), is clear about the different literals:

> **Floating-Point Literals**
>
> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it ends with the letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally end with the letter `D` or `d`.

There is a similiar case for **integer literals** but here the smaller type (`int`) is the default:

> **Integer Literals**
>
> An integer literal is of type `long` if it ends with the letter `L` or `l`; otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper case letter `L` because the lower case letter `l` is hard to distinguish from the digit `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`333.50` is a literal of type `double`. That's simply the rule - it comes from C way back in the 1970s. It's just like `0` is a literal of type `int`.

The equivalent `float` literal is `333.5f`, or you can use a compile time evaluable constant expression like `(float)333.50`.

Indeed `333.5` can be represented *exactly* as a `float` as it's a dyadic rational.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Java specification says that by default a floating-point literal is a `double` value.

> **Floating-Point Literals**
>
> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it ends with the letter `F`
>   or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally end with the
>   letter `D` or `d`.

Rather than using a narrowing conversion (`double` to `float`), just use the `F` prefix in the literal declaration :

```
 float f = 333.50F;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define  literals in java ([JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10))

```
int a = 12;
long b = 12L;
float c = 12.0f;
double d = 12.0d;
```

so you can write those like;

```
i = 1222;
```

is an integer literal

and the same way

```
j = 3.1415;
```

is a double literal

of course you can EXPLICITLY define the type:

```
i = 1222L;    //for long values
j = 3.1415f;  //for float values
```

Answer (score 0):

Java by default treats any decimal point values as the double. so you need to particularly define which type of primitive data type you are using.
for example:

```
`int i=10;         // default
long l=123456L; 
float f=123.12F;
double d=123.12345; // default
```

`
so you must explicitly define the what type of data type you are using when not using the default types